# Dev C++ gives different result in case of pointer address

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I have a following set of codes

```
int main(){
   int x = 36;
   int const * p1;
   p1 = &x;

   printf("Values at p1: %d\n", *p1); 
   p1=0;

   printf("Addresses pointed to by p1: %p ", &p1); 
   return 0;
}
```

gives

```
Addresses pointed to by p1 gives 0028FF480

   int main(){
   int x = 36;
   int const * p1;
   p1 = &x;

   printf("Values at p1: %d\n", *p1); 
   p1=0;

   printf("Addresses pointed to by p1: %p ", p1); 
   return 0;
   }
```

Addresses pointed to by p1 gives 00000000

Why such a difference..?I thought both will give me same value.

Comment: Whay do you think that p1 and &p1 should be the same?

Comment: dev-c++ comes with an ancienct compiler. Try codeblocks or qtcreator or eclipse with cdt but not dev-c++.

Answer (score 1):

Both are different hence the difference in output.

`p1` returns the address of the variable pointed by the pointer.

`&p1` returns the address where the pointer `p1` itself is stored in memory.

Comment: And the pointer P1 is most likely stored in a very different place from the place it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Initially `p1` stores the address of `x` (which you obtained with `&x`). Later on you set `p1` to store a null address.

In the first snippet you decided to print not the address *stored* in `p1`, but the *address of* `p1` *itself*. `p1` is a variable like any other, and just like with the rest of them, `&p1` will give you the address of that variable. That's different from the value stored in it, which is accessible with `p1` and is what the second snippet prints.

[image: I like pictures]

Like any other variable, you cannot change the address of the variable `p1`, you can only change the value it stores, and in the case of a pointer it just so happens that value is an address.

Answer (score 0):

```
p1=0;
```

will set the pointer that points to "p1" to zero, not the content of it which should be done by

```
*p1=0;
```

Comment: it's a ponter to constant u cannot do that :)

Comment: In your example its not possible, but I said it to explain the difference. Its all that happens, in the first example you set the pointer to zero and display it, in the second you create a new pointer and display its address.